# Html.DropDownListFor make visible/not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the html helper fo a drop down menu ( Html.DropDownFor(...) ) in an MVC 3 project.

On loading the page, I want this drop down menu not visible.  It will become visible depending on a choice of another drop down menu on the same page.  I've written some JQuery to handle this which makes use of show() and hide().  This works for textboxes and labels but what I need is the correct syntax for the helper itself.  I've tried:

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.VariableOptionId, new { style = "display: none;" })%>
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.VariableOptionId, Visible = false })%>
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a class, for example **.dropdown** and use **$('.dropdown').toggle();** to toggle visibility.

The MVC Helper syntax would be:

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.VariableOptionId, new { @class = "dropdown" }) %>
```

A small code example would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle">Click me to toggle!</div>
<br>
<div>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS / Jquery**

```
$(document).delegate('.toggle', 'click', function () {
    $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8AKww/

Edited example: http://jsfiddle.net/8AKww/1/

Comment: I tried your example but it's not what I want.  I want the drop down to be not visible when the page is loaded and visible when an option from another dd menu is chosen.

Comment: I've edited my original post as I wasn't clear on what I wanted to do.

Comment: I've edited my original post. Added 'Edited example'. Check it out, see if that's what you need. You would only need two MVC DropDowns with classes instead of one.

Comment: Thanks Yushell.  Yes, I did something along those lines already.  The priciple is the same, I just called @change = "myJavascript" instead of a submit button.  Thanks for reposting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @model MvcApplication1.Models.ProductViewModel
    <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


      @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {    
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedMainCatId, new    SelectList(Model.MainCategory,"Value","Text"), "Select Main..")
          @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSubCatId, new SelectList(Model.SubCategory, "Value", "Text"), "Select Sub..")    
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
       }
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#SelectedMainCatId").change(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if(val == 'anycondition')
                 {
                         $("#SubCategory").hide();
                 } 
                 else
                        $("#SubCategory").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your example but it's not what I want.  I want the drop down to be not visible when the page is loaded and visible when an option from another dd menu is chosen.  Your example hides the dd on some change event.

Comment: I've edited my original post as I wasn't clear on what I wanted to do.